# Arrow in the middle of two subfigures

Tags: arrows

I'm trying to have get an arrow in the middle between two subfigures. However, the arrow gets down between the subfigures.

Here is the thing I try to write:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float,subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{figure}[H]   
\centering  
\begin{subfigure}{.25\textwidth}  
  \centering  
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2.5cm]{example-image-duck}  
  \caption{0}  
  \label{2o_1}  
\end{subfigure}%  
{\xrightleftharpoons{TS2}}%  
\begin{subfigure}{.25\textwidth}  
  \centering  
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2.5cm]{example-image-duck}  
  \caption{0.16 [eV]}  
  \label{2o_2}  
\end{subfigure}  
    \caption{.....}  
    \label{fig:Co_O_Co_2O}  
\end{figure}
```

Here is my result:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please provide compilable code. Your lack both a `\documentclass`macro and a `document` environment. Also, your code doesn't compile due to missing `$`.

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot the position indications for the subfigures. Here's the code, including corrections for a couple of syntax errors.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float,subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering  
\begin{subfigure}[m]{.25\textwidth}  % position indicator here
  \centering  
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2.5cm]{example-image-duck}  
  \caption{0}  
  \label{2o_1}  
\end{subfigure}
$\xrightleftharpoons{TS2}$
\begin{subfigure}[m]{.25\textwidth}  % and here
  \centering  
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2.5cm]{example-image-duck}  
  \caption{0.16 [eV]}  
  \label{2o_2}  
\end{subfigure}  
    \caption{.....}  
    \label{fig:Co_O_Co_2O}  
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]